# gpg not listing local user keys

Tags: gnupg

I created a key-pair with Kleopatra, and using it everything looks ok;
but when I use command line and try to list this key, I get a message:

```
sudo gpg --list-keys D87072B6
gpg: error reading key: public key not found
```

same happens if I try to list this key secret key:

```
sudo gpg --list-secret-keys D87072B6
gpg: error reading key: secret key not available’
```

I am missing something here; I just followed the instruction found on ‘https://wiki.debian.org/Subkeys’ to create new subkeys (quote):

"Create a new subkey for signing. 
Find your key ID: gpg –list-keys yourname"

I tried export a certificate of that key, and re-importing it, always with Kleopatra, to no avail.

Also, when I list keys with no specific name, it display the keys I have imported from the web; but not the keys belonging to me, that I have created on this computer; so I guess there’s something I am doing wrongly, but can’t guess what.

Can anyone point me to what is wrong?

Gpg –version says gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.20

Answer (score 1):

If you run `gpg` with `sudo`, you are in effect running gpg as the root user. Thus you are trying to find the keys associated with the root user's gpg keyring, located in `/root/.gnupg`.

I am guessing you want to list the keys in **your** keyring, in `/home/(username)/.gnupg`. To that end, what happens if you run

`gpg --list-keys`

You should see all the keys in your keyring. And your own key should be there.

This assumes that Kleopatra is setup in such a way that it places the  public-private key-pair you created in the `~/.gnupg` directory.

PS - If you are going to use gpg on the command line, I recommend you install `apt-get install gnupg2`.