# How do I get gpg to actually add keys properly?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

I've tried following along with this tutorial: https://linuxhint.com/generate-pgp-keys-gpg/

I used

```
sudo gpg --full-generate-key
```

and it seemed to be happy enough but when I tried

```
gpg --list-keys
```

Nothing!

I looked for the directory it said it used to store the revocation certificate and it doesn't seem to exist.

```
/root/.gnupg/openpgp-revocs.d/blah...
```

root exists but .gnupg does not, which makes me think that gpg is failing silently.

Any ideas?

I am trying to do this all on the command line - it should work on the command line, I do NOT want to use a GUI to do this. I have got this to work on other systems before, on the command line.

Comment: It takes some time to generate a key.

Comment: No? It's told me that it's already generated the key. It says "public and secret key created and signed."

Comment: Why run it with `sudo`? You added the key to `root` instead of your user. And also `.gnupg does not` it is wrong. It is a hidden directory. Please add output of `ls -a /root` to your question.

Comment: Why indeed. I guess I need a better quality tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I got it, from this question: [gpg not listing local user keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067848/gpg-not-listing-local-user-keys?rq=1)

I couldn't mark the answer as correct but as the chap suggested, I just needed to run sudo on the gpg --list-keys command

'''
sudo gpg --list-keys
'''

Sure enough, it worked!

Comment: It was wrong to generate key with sudo.